# Initializing JavaScript class before using it later in an html file

Tags: javascript, html, web-deployment

I have the following problem. I developed a javaScript class that is being used in conjunction with a select tag. Since the javaScript class has to parse through the DOM of the page, I would rather initialize the class once the DOM finishes loading and not necessarily when the user chooses a value from the select element. I was wondering what would be the best practice to do this.

I currently have the following code in the head:

```
<script>
    window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
  
      // As soon as DOM content is loaded initialize class and have class parse through DOM     
      obj = new Object();
      
    });
</script>
```

and the following select down in the body:

```
<select name="select" id="select" onChange="obj.function(this);">
    <option value="value1">Value1</option>
    <option value="value2">Value2</option>
</select>
```

However, when I run this I get an uncaught reference error for obj. What would be the best practice for this?

Comment: "I would rather initialize the class once the DOM finishes loading and not necessarily when the user chooses a value from the select element.": Can you explain what this means? What is your code meant to do?

Comment: You should declare `obj` eg. `const obj = new Object();`

Comment: Andy, I know I could initialize the class within the select, but I would prefer that it would be initialized as soon as the page loads. My code is meant to parse through the DOM tree and change DOM elements when a value is clicked. The first snippet also helps to maintain the DOM changes if the user reloads the page, since I am caching the changes to cookies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should bind select event onChange after that document is ready to use new instance.

```html
<script>
    window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
  
      // As soon as DOM content is loaded initialize class and have class parse through DOM     
      obj = new Object();
      sel = document.getElementById('select')
      sel.onChange = obj.function(sel)
    });
</script>

...

<select name="select" id="select">
    <option value="value1">Value1</option>
    <option value="value2">Value2</option>
</select>
```